# How do you realign the vertexs in a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So i was working on a donut (I'm relatively new to blender) and accidently messed up part of my mesh in the process and is there any good way to fix the mesh without manually trying to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can delete this part:

[image]

Select the 2 opposite edges:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Edit mode select the affected vertices, then Vertex > Relax, then in the option pop-up (lower left corner) set the Relax Iterations up (maybe around 16 for that, at a guess).  It won't be perfect, but it'll get a lot better.

[image]